# transfer data from child to child form and open child2 from the parent

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am able to transfer data from child1 to child2 form no problem and open child2 from the child1 form.But I need to open child2 form the Main menu bar and to have transfered data there in the textboxes.Data doesn't get to the child2 then I open the child2 from the parent form.
Here is the code:
Child1 (Officer Login)

```
public string s;

public string Param
{
   get { return s; }
   set { s = value; }
}

public void LoginMethod()
{

   try
   {

       OfficerBO user = new OfficerBO ();
       user.OfficerID = txtOfficerId.Text;
       user.Password = hs.PassHash(txtPassword.Text);


       if (user.Login())
       {
            s = user.LastName;           

            MessageBox.Show("You Loged in Successfully\n\n" + user.FirstName +
                " " + user.LastName ); 
            OnLoginSuccess(null, null);               

            // this.Hide();
            HolidayApp h = new HolidayApp(); 
            // Data gets transfered into Child2 (HolidayApp) form 
            //and dialog opens no problem
            h.ParamSet = Param;
            h.ShowDialog();
       }
       else
       {
            txtOfficerId.Text = "";
            txtPassword.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid details");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Child2 (HolidayApp):

```
public string ParamSet
{
    get { return txtHolidaySurname.Text; }
    set { txtHolidaySurname.Text = value; }
}
public void HolidayApp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtHolidaySurname.Text = ParamSet;
}
```

I need help on: On successeful login I need to open HolidayApp (Child2) from the Main menu bar and to have users details in the textboxes. Pls help or advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right your code then
Your property `ParamSet` not keeping any data, but just read and set value of `txtHolidaySurname.Text`

So if after `Form_Load` textbox is empty, then maybe `txtHolidaySurname.Text` was reset to default value ('') after `h.ParamSet=Param`.

try just save a name and then put in textbox in `Form_Load`

```
private string sParam;
public string ParamSet
{
    get { return this.sParam;}
    set { this.sParam=value;}
}
```

In `Form_Load` will be the same code....

Comment: Thank for the reply.I tried everyhting I think I am missing something.I put the code in form_Load but then form loads data is not there.

Comment: @user2064345 id txtHolidaySurname.Text empty? Did you put my code in Child2(HolidayApp) form?